# How to remove labeling and tickering in WFDB, python?

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3idd.png)

The plots have label and tick information and I'd like to remove them.

I downloaded ECG data from Pysionet(https://physionet.org/content/?topic=ecg) and try to analze the images.
Since I just need the signal images, want to remove any other parts including labels and ticks.
However, there are no parameters related to it and doesn't work with any plt options.
How could I get just the sinal images?

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to the matplotlib figure generated by wfdb_plot via `return_fig=True`. This way, you can disable any axis annotations and titles:

```py
fig = wfdb.plot_wfdb(record=rcbr, figsize=(10,4), return_fig=True) 
fig.axes.axis("off")  # disable ticks, labels, etc.
fig.axes.set_title("")  # remove title
```